# Update CustomControl on ItemsSource item changed

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Extending Calendar control, I have added ItemsSource DependencyProperty to allow me to display ToolTips and highlight CalendarDayButtons using provided Color. ItemsSource is of type `IEnumerable<CalendarDay>` where CalendarDay is a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

CalendarDay.cs

```
public class CalendarDay : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private DateTime date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return date;
        }
        set
        {
            if (date == value) return;

            date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }

    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (description == value) return;

            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    private string color;
    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }
        set
        {
            if (color == value) return;

            color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

    public CalendarDay()
    {

    }
}
```

Custom Control: ExtendedCalendar.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemsSource",
    typeof(IEnumerable<CalendarDay>),
    typeof(ExtendedCalendar),
    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged))
);

private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ExtendedCalendar control)
        control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable<CalendarDay>)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable<CalendarDay>)e.NewValue);
}

private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable<CalendarDay> oldValue, IEnumerable<CalendarDay> newValue)
{
    if (oldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
    {
        oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(NewValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
    }
    if (newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
    {
        newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(NewValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
    }
}

void NewValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

While using my custom control in different project referencing the control, the collection is to be updated on MenuItem click through a command in ViewModel.

CalendarViewModel.cs (where DefinedDates is of type `ObservableCollection<CalendarDay>`)

```
private void DefineNewDate(DateTime date, bool toWorkDay)
{
    DefinedDates.Add(new CalendarDay
    {
        Date = date,
        Description = toWorkDay ? "Work Day" : "Day Off",
        Color = toWorkDay ? "Green" : "OrangeRed"
    });
}

private void UpdateDefined(CalendarDay calendarDay, bool toWorkDay)
{
    var calendarDateToUpdate = DefinedDates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date == calendarDay.Date);
    if(calendarDateToUpdate != null)
    {
        calendarDateToUpdate.Description = toWorkDay ? "Work Day" : "Day Off";
        calendarDateToUpdate.Color = toWorkDay ? "Green" : "OrangeRed";
    }
}
```

While debugging I can see that `Refresh()` is only done on `DefineNewDate(DateTime date, bool toWorkDay)` and updating already contained item is not detected.

Comment: The question is why you would expect anything else than this behavior. Setting the properties of an element of the DefinedDates collection neither modifies the collection nor does it change the ItemsSource property. In order to update the UI, CalendarDay should correctly implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Clemens as mentioned, CalendarDay implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Will add code, as I may have missed something while doing it and it's not correct. Also it is placed in my ExtendedCalendarControl Custom Control project, not sure if it's a correct approach.

Comment: Setting CalendarDay properties will not magically call Refresh(), if that was your question. It will just update Bindings of the UserControl's child elements, in case you have declared them.

Comment: @Clemens All right, the logic in ResourceDirectory is done mostly using converters not binding to properties directly, so I can see that casues the UI no to update as changing properties itself does not invoke OnItemsSourceChanged